# Reading only one Column of an excel file using RODBC

Tags: r

Is it possible to read only one columnof an excel file using RODBC? How can do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get column `name` from sheet `sheetname`

```
library(RODBC)

sheet = 'my_excel.xls'
con = odbcConnectExcel(sheet)
#tbls = sqlTables(con)
dfr <- sqlQuery(con,"SELECT name FROM `sheetname$`")

close(con)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, the columns in my excel file dont have any name, I have tried this code: `dfr <- sqlQuery(jo,"SELECT A FROM `Tabelle1$`")` but I get this error: `[1] "07002 -3010 [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1."
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT A FROM `Tabelle1$`'"       `

Comment: See column TABLE_NAME of tbls in the above code. Maybe you will find out what is the `name` you should use.

Comment: the name of the table is correct, but How can I retrieve the data from A in my excel file?

Comment: "SELECT top 1 F1 FROM `Sheet1$`"

Comment: Thanks, but still the same problem

Comment: Do you put sheetname between "`" (backquotes)?